# IDEA. How to find a method by its return type

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

By pressing Ctrl + Space I can find what methods are available in the class. But suppose I don't know the name of the method but I know a return type. Can I somehow specify it and find all methods of the class that match the type?

Comment: Does https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206639555/comments/205789465 works?

Comment: @Martheen Yes it works, but sometimes I don't want to use exactly the return value (for example I want to get a collection to compute something in stream) or I don't want use the value at all (like boolean values that tell me that a method completed successfully)

Comment: That got into backlog since 2015 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7191, it's not a blocking issue and seems to be rarely useful.